# Doctrine one to many relationship issue

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have two entities

The resortrooms and the inventory entites

The resort rooms has one to many relations with inventory.

What I need to do is to apply a conditions to the inventory tables.

I already made a query using DQL but it gives all results from inventory.Its not applying the conditions.

```
 $qb->select('ih.id,rr')
            ->from('\Base\Entity\Avp\ResortRooms', 'rr')
            ->leftJoin('rr.inventory','ih');

 if($data['numMales']):
                        $qb->andWhere('ih.malesCount >= :males')
                        ->setParameter("males",(int)$data['numMales']);
```

I want a results from inventory whose malesCount is 2.

**Below are my two entities**

**ResortRooms**

```
class ResortRooms extends \Base\Entity\Base\BaseEntity
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    protected $title;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $description;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="resort_id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $resortId;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="price", type="decimal", precision=10, scale=0, nullable=false)
     */
    protected $price = '0';

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="image", type="string", length=50, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $image;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="meta_title", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $metaTitle;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="last_updated", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $lastUpdated;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="in_stock", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $inStock = '0';

     /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Base\Entity\InventoryHotels", mappedBy="roomId")
     */
    protected $inventory;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->inventory = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getInventory() {
        return $this->inventory;
      }
```

**Inventory Hotels**

```
class InventoryHotels extends Base\BaseEntity
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="resort_id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $resortId;

    /**
     * @var \Base\Entity\Avp\ResortRooms
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Base\Entity\Avp\ResortRooms",inversedBy="inventory")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="room_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */

    protected $roomId;
```

Comment: going out on a limb here with the data provided, but is it possible 'numMales' is null, false, or empty? and thus the condition never gets applied?

Comment: @AnjanaSilva thats precisely what im talking about. He says "but it gives all results from inventory.Its not applying the conditions.". Well, going by whats provided here, there is only one `where`, and it's dictated to say "if $data['numMales'] is valid, as in not empty, null, or false, then add this where clause".   Hence my question: IS at the time of executing this query, nuMales somehow false, empty, or null, and thusly avoids adding the where clause altogether?

Comment: no the $data['numMales'] is 3 ,its not empty.

Comment: Ok, when rendering the page, click on the Doctrine item in the profiler, find the query and click on "Display Runnable Query", copy and paste that query here

Comment: i have edited the above question and posted the entities.Now you may better understand what I need exactly.

Comment: I'm not so sure, the problem is with this where clauses right? As far as you've told us, the entities themselves aren't a problem. I'd hope you'd have told us by now if there was a hydration or association problem.  If you dont want to show us the whole Query Builder bit, mind showing us the runnable query that's being generated as I mentioned earlier?

Answer (score 0):

could you post the full queries? i dont see a where in the first one nor the second entity.

the andWhere() is used when there is a where in the first place. but if its possible i would suggest keeping it cleaner and going for multiple params in the same where:

```
->where(array('param1' => 1, 'param2' => 2))->setParameters()
```

if the relationship is bidirectional you can go for repository:

```
 $em->getRepository('Repo:Entity')->findByMalesCount($data['numMales']);
```